Will dynamodb client automatically retry for retryable error?
If the dynamodb client is initialized in this way, without specifying anything related to retry, will the client automatically retry 3 times for retryable errors? Thanks.
newSession := session.Must(session.NewSession())
dynamo := dynamodb.New(newSession)

